# How can I create an arbitrary superposition state of two qubits in Qiskit?

Tags: qiskit, programming

I am trying to produce any arbitrary superposition state of two qubits, for example $a|00\rangle + b|01\rangle + c|10\rangle + d|11\rangle$, such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 = 1$ . How can I do that with Qiskit?

One way that I have found out is to use $U_3(\theta, 0, 0)$ gates for suitable values of $\theta$ on both of the qubits. Is there another way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`qiskit.quantum_info` has a useful [random_statevector](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.random_statevector.html) function that you can use to generate a random statevector that's sampled from the uniform measure.
For a 2-qubit state, you would call it as follows:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import random_statevector
state = random_statevector(4) # note: the parameter you pass is the number of entries in the vector, not the number of qubits
```

Once you have this statevector, the [initialize](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.initialize.html#qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.initialize) function lets you initialize your qubits to the state you just created. The documentation for `initialize` is not very helpful so here's how you would use it:

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.initialize(state.data, [0,1])
```

Note that you will have to use `state.data` to get the underlying array representing the statevector, because `initialize` doesn't accept an argument of type `StateVector`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Putting my answer here just for completeness.
Initialise 2 qubits with random state in a quantum circuit, that's it, you will have what you need. After that you can use statevector_simulator to verify the final superposition state. You can also use plot_bloch_multivector to view it.

I made code a bit verbose for clarity.

Code

```
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, execute
from qiskit.quantum_info.states.random import random_statevector
from qiskit.extensions import Initialize
from qiskit.visualization import plot_bloch_multivector

state_backend = Aer.get_backend('statevector_simulator')

def initrstate(qc, label=""):
   state = random_statevector((2,1)).data
   print(state) # if you want to see what state you have initialized the qubit to
   init = Initialize(state)
   init.label = label
   return init

def viewstate(qc):
   result = execute(qc, state_backend).result()
   fstate = result.get_statevector()
   print(fstate) # This will be the superposition state
   return fstate

qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
init1 = initrstate(qc)
init2 = initrstate(qc)
qc.append(init1, [0])
qc.append(init2, [1])

plot_bloch_multivector(viewstate(qc)) #Plot the state vectors on the bloch sphere
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding my answer as well to fill out the other suggestions. You can use this to construct a circuit based on an arbitrary state vector: https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.aqua.circuits.StateVectorCircuit.construct_circuit.html#qiskit.aqua.circuits.StateVectorCircuit.construct_circuit

You initialize StateVectorCircuit with your array of complex values.