# Reducing circuit initialization complexity

Tags: qiskit, transpile, initialization

I'm encoding data into a QuantumCircuit via the Initialize method for QFTs. In doing this and transpiling for IonQ backends, I'm getting rather complex circuits. Is there a way to encode this data more efficiently for IonQ backends or a method to approximate this circuit? Thanks in advance!

[image: Encoding a sine wave into an 8 qbit register, then transpiling for IonQ sim backend]

Answer (score 1):

I think that the `QuantumCircuit.initialize()` method isn't always providing the most efficient state preparations.

I have tried to initialize some very simple states, like $|11⟩$ for 2-qubits system:

1. In the first case I just used simple 2 NOT gates (which are also native gates in all the quantum computers that I know), so the the transpiled version is pretty much the same:

[image]

2. In the second case I have used `qc.initialize([0,0,0,1])` to initialize the same $|11⟩$ state and the results are very ugly:

[image]

Along with [this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15434/issue-with-speed-of-qiskit-arbitrary-initialization) talking I can infer that `QuantumCircuit.initialize()`  isn't providing always the most efficient method for setting a desired state. And that's probably the reason that so many gates are used in order to set the 8-qubits state above.

Try to set up the desired state manually (I don't understand exactly which state you are trying to initialize here so I can't tell you exactly how to do it for now).

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`isometry`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.circuit.QuantumCircuit.isometry.html) instead of `initialize`:

```
qc.isometry(y/np.linalg.norm(y), [*range(n_qubits)], [])
```

Also, try setting `optimization_level` to 3 for `transpile` method. Most of the time this will reduce number of gates.

```
qc1 = transpile(circuits=qc, backend=backend, optimization_level=3)
```